# FlywayDB - afterBaseline

Tags: flyway

I have a clean DB that I want to run a "seeding" script on after the initial V1 migration.

Will the `afterBaseline` callback be called after an initial migration to a clean DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to only be called after the `baseline` command is executed, and not after the initial migration.

The solution I took was to create a "V2" migration that contained my DML/seeding data.

Comment: Have you found any "better" approach to this issue?